# OBJECT NAVIGATORUSERMEDIAERROR appears on audio recording that runs on linux server

Tags: javascript, linux

Hi I would like to seek help on how I can enable or be able to allow linux to get or take audio recording from other pc. What I mean is my web application is currently hosted on my linux server which is currently live, my problem now is I I receive this error:

- NO LIVE AUDIO INPUT: [OBJECT NAVIGATORUSERMEDIAERROR]

On my logs: NAVIGATOR.GETUSERMEDIA is AVAILABLE but it seems that it can't capture recordings. Below is my code. Please help me be enlightened. Pardon me for asking I'm actually beginner on this. here is my javascript code.

```
  <script>
  function __log(e, data) {
    log.innerHTML += "\n" + e + " " + (data || '');
  }

  var audio_context;
  var recorder;

  function startUserMedia(stream) {
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    __log('Media stream created.' );
    __log("input sample rate " +input.context.sampleRate);

    // Feedback!
    //input.connect(audio_context.destination);
    __log('Input connected to audio context destination.');

    recorder = new Recorder(input, {
                  numChannels: 1
                });
    __log('Recorder initialised.');
  }

  function startRecording(button) {
    recorder && recorder.record();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Recording...');
  }

  function stopRecording(button) {
    recorder && recorder.stop();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.previousElementSibling.disabled = true;
    __log('Stopped recording.');

    // create WAV download link using audio data blob
    createDownloadLink();

    recorder.clear();
  }

  function createDownloadLink() {
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
      /*var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var au = document.createElement('audio');
      var hf = document.createElement('a');

      au.controls = true;
      au.src = url;
      hf.href = url;
      hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
      hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
      li.appendChild(au);
      li.appendChild(hf);
      recordingslist.appendChild(li);*/
    });
  }

  window.onload = function init() {
    try {
      // webkit shim
      window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

      audio_context = new AudioContext;
      __log('Audio context set up.');
      __log('navigator.getUserMedia ' + (navigator.getUserMedia ? 'available.' : 'not present!'));
    } catch (e) {
      alert('No web audio support in this browser!');
    }

    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
      __log('No live audio input: ' + e);
    });
  };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

navigator.getUserMedia() API has recently (maybe Dec '15) been removed from browsers. I have the same problem, it looks like MediaRecorder() API solves the problem - though I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). I'll try it anyway.